# Rearranging elements a grid based on visibility in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, grid

I have a grid with 3 rows and 4 columns. Lets say in row third, there are 4 controls named A, B, C and D. 
When the visibility of control "A" is collapse , then B control should replace the control A, C should replace B and D should replace C
so the row third will have control in sequence B,C and D(since A is invisible)

Could you please suggest how this can be achieved in C#(silverlight).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a stackpanel in the row third and put your controls A,B,C and D in the stack panel.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion...I want to align the controls on the third with the controls on the second row.. is it possible if i use stack panel??